# underscore map key name w/ increment

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, underscore.js, increment

I have a js object like:

```
[{"product":7001,"quantity":1},{"product":3002,"quantity":1},{"product":4002,"quantity":4}]
```

I need to be able to rename the keys incrementally, ex:

```
[{"product":7001,"quantity":1},{"product1":3002,"quantity1":1},{"product2":4002,"quantity2":4}]
```

I have been working on something which adds an increment to the key name, but this doesn't work with the type of object I'm using.

Any advice would be appreciated. ty.

```
/*
this doesn't work
var a = [
  {product : "3002", quantity: 1},
  {product : "4001", quantity : 3}
  ];
*/

// this updates the key, but not in the way I need it to.
var a =  {product : "3002", quantity: 1}

  var n = 0;

  function increment(string)
  {
    n++
      return string + n;
  }

  var b = {};

  var map = {
      name : "name"
  };

  var keymap = {};
  _.each(a, function(value, key) {
      var oldkey = key;
      key = increment(key);
      keymap[oldkey] = key;
  });
  _.each(a, function(value, key) {
      key = keymap[key] || key;
      b[key] = value;
  });

  console.log('increment keys: ' + JSON.stringify(b));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an unusual request and unusual structure but here's a map/reduce that produces expected results

```js
var data = [{"product":7001,"quantity":1},{"product":3002,"quantity":1},{"product":4002,"quantity":4}],

res = data.map((o,i)=>Object.keys(o).reduce((o2, key)=> i ? (o2[key+i] = o[key],o2):o,{}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: this is late in response but is it possible to get the increment starting at 1 e.g. "product1":"quantity1" ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a better idea. Why not add an ID key to the object instead of change the key name. The following code loops through the array and creates a new array. The objects in the new array now have an `id` key that corresponds to the index of the product.

```js
    let products = [{"product":7001,"quantity":1},{"product":3002,"quantity":1},{"product":4002,"quantity":4}];

    products = products.map((item, index) => Object.assign(item, { id: index + 1 }));

    console.log(products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array with [`_.map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map). Because underscore lacks the ability to map keys, you can [`_.invert()`](http://underscorejs.org/#invert) the keys and the values, update the keys (the current values) with [`_.mapObject()`](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject), and then `_.invert()` again:

```js
var data = [{"product":7001,"quantity":1},{"product":3002,"quantity":1},{"product":4002,"quantity":4}]

var result = _.map(data, function(o, i) {
  return _.chain(o)
    .invert()
    .mapObject(function(v) { return v + (i || '') })
    .invert()
    .value()
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

It's much easier to do this in ES6 using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
var data = [{"product":7001,"quantity":1},{"product":3002,"quantity":1},{"product":4002,"quantity":4}]

var result = data.map(({ product, quantity }, i) => ({
  [`product${i || ''}`]: product,
  [`quantity${i || ''}`]: quantity
}));

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```